# keep one subfigure fixed and move another subfigure towards right

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

[image]

Hi.I would like to shift the subfigure (b) towards right side, aligned exactly with the line at the top of this figure.

```
\begin{figure*} 
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{a.pdf}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1.8in, width=2.3in]{b.pdf}
\caption
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Why don't you use `\subcaptionbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have determined that the second figure should be 1.8in high, then `\subcaptionbox` is what you want:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% the following are just for the example
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % mock text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % just to show the top rule
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\kant

\begin{figure*} 
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=1.8in]{example-image-16x9.pdf}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=1.8in, width=2.3in]{example-image-9x16.pdf}}

\caption{Cumulative caption}
\end{figure*}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]